# Using ModelForm in Django to add to database

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

New to Django and I have exhausted every forum and tutorial I can and I am still having problems getting my form data to the database. I have a simple model that consists of a name and an email field that I will eventually reference in the program. I can load different pages after clicking submit, but my data will not post to the database. I have tried everything I can think of, so my code is probably jacked at this point, but in the current iteration this is what I have:

```
#models.py
    from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Patron(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)


    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.name

class PatronForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patron

#view.py

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from patrons.models import Patron 
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.forms import ModelForm


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        name = post['name']
        email = post['email']
        f = PatronForm(request.Post)
        new_patron = f.save()
    return render_to_response('patrons/index.html',
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#html
 <body>
    <h1>/Picture Taker/</h1>



    <form aciton="." name="patron" method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}

        <label>
            <div>name</div> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{name}}">
        </label>
        <label>
            <div>email</div> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="{{email}}">
        </label>

        <div class="error">{{error}}</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of

```
post = request.POST
name = post['name']
email = post['email']
f = PatronForm(request.Post)
new_patron = f.save()
```

can be re-written as (note the case of `request.POST`):

```
f = PatronForm(request.POST)
new_patron = f.save()
```

but you should be checking for errors in the form before saving, so:

```
f = PatronForm(request.POST)
if f.is_valid():
    new_patron = f.save()
```

You also have a typo in your form tag, it should be "action", not "aciton". The {{ error }} you have in your template doesn't refer to anything present in your view. While debugging, it might be helpful to let the form render itself, like:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

so you can see any errors in the form submission.

Comment: Thanks@Tom                                                         Now I get this error when I try to submit                                                                                                                                     global name 'PatronForm' is not defined
11  f = PatronForm(request.POST) ...
▶ Local vars

Comment: In views.py, you need to import your form. It should really be in a separate file called "forms.py" for consistency, but in your case it looks like "from patron.models import PatronForm"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "every forum and tutorial", you just need the official documentation, where [this is explained clearly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view). The only change from the code you see at that link is that you need to add `form.save()` inside the bit that says "Process the data" (and, you should use RequestContext in the render_to_response call, as you already do).

The other thing to change is that you should rely on Django to render the whole field in the template, not just the value:

```
<p>
{{ form.name }} 
{{ form.name.errors }}
</p>

<p>
{{ form.email }}
{{ form.email.errors }}
</p>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm getting the following after making changes to my code:         global name 'PatronForm' is not defined    with the following errors Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/curtis/picturetaketest3/mysite/patrons/views.py" in index
  11.   f = PatronForm(request.POST)

Comment: Well, you haven't imported it into your view.